# Ativar tecla TAB para proximo campo em RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um formulário onde possuo um campo "nome de usuário", neste campo eu uso esta `RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z \b]+$")` , funciona perfeitamente, porém na hora que uso a tecla TAB para avançar para o próximo campo ela não funciona! Já tentei usar `\t`, mas sem sucesso.
Alguma sujestão?

Segue código:

```
$('#usuario').bind('keypress', function (event){
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z \b]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

    if (!regex.test(key)){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Poderia demostrar como esta usando esta regex? por `input pattern`? `mark`, ou mesmo uma função? esta aplicado em um `replace`?

Comment: Teria como você postar seu código? Ou uma parte dele?

Comment: Postei o código

Comment: Qual navegador você está utilizando? Qual tipo de entrada é o elemento usuario? Testei o seu código aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: O navegador é o FireFox v44, bem colocado, eu testei no chrome e realmente funcionou, o problema seria no FireFox?

Comment: O problema em 99% (Para não dizer 100%) dos casos é o nosso código. Os navegadores tem suas diferenças e temos que fazer um código que se adeque a todos (ou os mais utilizados).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui algo que funcionou para mim.

```
$('#usuario').bind('keypress', function (event){
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z \b\0]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

    if (!regex.test(key)){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }
});
```

**Explicação:**

Você está testando com o regex o output da tecla que você está apertando, porém quando você aperta a tecla tab em um elemento HTML, era não gera o output que nós esperamos \t, mas sim executa uma ação de mudar de elemento. Então o seu output é nulo, o escape em javascript para nulo é \0.

Talvez você não tivesse percebido, mas as suas teclas direcionais não estavam funcionando também.

Você tratar pelo código da tecla, mas acredito que tratar todas as teclas que são necessárias para o funcionamento esperado irá poluir o seu código.

**Referência:**

[JavaScript RegExp Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: Testei com o seu código e funcionou perfeitamente, ótima explicação me ajudou muito; como você disse, eu não tinha notado que as direcionais também não funcionavam!
Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Teste Assim :

```
$('#usuario').bind('keypress', function (event){
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z \b]+$");
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

    // 9 é o keyCode do tab        
    if (!regex.test(String.fromCharCode(keyCode)) && keyCode != 9){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```