# Apenas texto Input javascript

Tags: javascript

Opa,

Coisa bem simples que não encontrei algo similar, resolvi então criar, fiz:

```
    function bloqueiaNumero(texto)
    {
     var tecla = new String();

     if (window.event) {
      tecla = texto.keyCode;
     }
     else if (texto.which) {
      tecla = texto.which;
     }
     else {
      return true;
     }

        if (((tecla < 48) || (tecla > 57)) && (tecla = 8))
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
          return false;
        }

    }
```

Certo, tá bloqueando números, mas, deveria bloquear também os keycodes acima de 57 e não está :(
Ou seja, quero que seja possível digitar apenas de 'A a Z' minusculo

O que ha de errado?

```
 onKeyPress="return bloqueiaNumero(event);"
```

Answer (score 1):

Patrão usa regex, funfa legal também...

```js
function valida_az(){
 var filter_az = /^([a-z]|\s)+$/ ;
 if(!filter_az.test(document.getElementById("input_az").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_az").value="";
 document.getElementById("input_az").value = "Somente a-z";
 document.getElementById("input_az").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_az").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_az").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_az").onkeydown = function (){
 document.getElementById("input_az").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_az").style.outline = null;}
 }
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="valida_az.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="" onsubmit="valida_az(this);return false;">
  <input id="input_az" type="text" onblur="valida_az()">
  <input type="submit"  class="btn_enviar_cad"  name="enviar_cad"  value="Enviar"  >
</form>
```

Vê se curte... Ai se adapta..

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acredito que o erro é de lógica, no seu if. Tenta colocar ele assim:

```
if ((tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57) || (tecla === 8))
```

Answer (score 0):

O que eu entendi foi que você deseja que possam ser digitado apenas letras de "a" até "z" (apenas minúsculos). O KeyCode deles vai de 97 até 117.

Refiz seu código e ele ficou assim:

```js
function bloqueiaNumero(texto){
  var tecla = texto.which || texto.keyCode;
  if ((tecla >= 97 && tecla <= 117) || (tecla === 8)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" onKeyPress="return bloqueiaNumero(event);">
</form>
```

Uma observação, você se lembrou do Backspace, mas não será necessário utilizar a tecla de espaço nos seus campos ? Se for, lembre de acrescentar outro || para o keyCode 32.

Deus nos Abençoe!

Answer (score 0):

"quero que seja possível digitar apenas de 'A a Z' minusculo"...

Se vc quer apenas caracteres minúsculos e mais nada, seria melhor usar REGEX com javascript.

Tenta essa solução:

```
//HTML
<input class='txt' type='text' value=''>

//Javascript
    $('.txt').bind({             

             keyup:function(){

                   var objectEvent=$(this);
                   var ck_input = /^[a-z]+$/;
                   var input = $.trim(objectEvent.val());
                   var validationTest =ck_input.test(input);

                     if(input!==""){
                       if(!validationTest){
                                objectEvent.val("");
                            alert("nao aceita");
                       } 
                   }  
             }//Fim keyUp
    });//Fim of $('.txt').bind({
```

Ele só vai deixar no imput o que vc solicitou, caracteres minúsculos.
Aqui o [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/cscr330p/) funcional.

Answer (score 0):

exatamente como [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118280/14711) o que você quer é limitar os caracteres que são digitados.

Adaptei o código que estava sendo utilizado na outra resposta para poder se adequar ao seu problema:

```
function bloqueioNumero (event){
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z \b\0]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

    if (!regex.test(key)){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basicamente o código utiliza de expressões regulares e permite letras (a-z) minusculas como você solicitou, (\b) backspace, espaço em branco e (\0) qualquer tecla que tenha o retorno nulo, ou seja, qualquer tecla que não imprima algo na tela, backspace, tab, setas e etc.